# gcc cannot do ./configure apache

Tags: compiling, gcc, solaris

I tried to install apache on solaris. While I did know I can do this by pkg install apache-ver, this doesn't allow me to install to custom directory.

```
CC='/usr/bin/gcc' ./configure --prefix=/opt/app/apache --with-pcre=~/Downloads/pcre-8.40
checking for chosen layout... Apache
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/ggrep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/ggrep -E
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking target system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
configure: 
configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library...
configure: 
checking for APR... yes
setting CPP to "cc -m32 -E"
setting CFLAGS to " "
setting CPPFLAGS to " -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64"
setting LDFLAGS to " "
configure: 
configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime Utility library...
configure: 
checking for APR-util... yes
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -m32 -E
configure: error: in `/export/home/admin/Downloads/Normal_apache/httpd-2.4.25':
configure: error: C preprocessor "cc -m32 -E" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
```

It fail sanity check.

Here its the log

```
## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = solaris
uname -m = i86pc
uname -r = 5.11
uname -s = SunOS
uname -v = 11.3

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = System = SunOS
Node = solaris
Release = 5.11
KernelID = 11.3
Machine = i86pc
BusType = <unknown>
Serial = <unknown>
Users = <unknown>
OEM# = 0
Origin# = 1
NumCPU = 2

/bin/arch              = i86pc
/usr/bin/arch -k       = i86pc
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3098: checking for chosen layout
configure:3100: result: Apache
configure:3903: checking for working mkdir -p
configure:3919: result: yes
configure:3928: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:3986: result: /usr/bin/ggrep
configure:3991: checking for egrep
configure:4053: result: /usr/bin/ggrep -E
configure:4069: checking build system type
configure:4083: result: i386-pc-solaris2.11
configure:4103: checking host system type
configure:4116: result: i386-pc-solaris2.11
configure:4136: checking target system type
configure:4149: result: i386-pc-solaris2.11
configure:4179: 
configure:4181: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library...
configure:4183: 
configure:4224: checking for APR
configure:4369: result: yes
configure:4629: 
configure:4631: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime Utility library...
configure:4633: 
configure:4670: checking for APR-util
configure:4749: result: yes
configure:5010: checking for gcc
configure:5037: result: /usr/bin/gcc
configure:5266: checking for C compiler version
configure:5275: /usr/bin/gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:5286: $? = 0
configure:5275: /usr/bin/gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/gcc/4.8/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i386-pc-solaris2.11
Configured with: /builds/hudson/workspace/nightly-update/build/i386/components/gcc48/gcc-4.8.2/configure CC=/usr/gcc/4.7/bin/gcc CXX=/usr/gcc/4.7/bin/g++ --prefix=/usr/gcc/4.8 --mandir=/usr/gcc/4.8/share/man --bindir=/usr/gcc/4.8/bin --libdir=/usr/gcc/4.8/lib --sbindir=/usr/gcc/4.8/sbin --infodir=/usr/gcc/4.8/share/info --libexecdir=/usr/gcc/4.8/lib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc --enable-shared --with-gmp-include=/usr/include/gmp --with-mpfr-include=/usr/include/mpfr --without-gnu-ld --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld --with-gnu-as --with-as=/usr/gnu/bin/as CFLAGS='-g -O2  -mtune=opteron -march=opteron' CXXFLAGS='-g -O2 -mtune=opteron -march=opteron'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC) 
configure:5286: $? = 0
configure:5275: /usr/bin/gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:5286: $? = 1
configure:5275: /usr/bin/gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:5286: $? = 1
configure:5306: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:5328: /usr/bin/gcc    -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   conftest.c  >&5
configure:5332: $? = 0
configure:5380: result: yes
configure:5383: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:5385: result: a.out
configure:5391: checking for suffix of executables
configure:5398: /usr/bin/gcc -o conftest    -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   conftest.c  >&5
configure:5402: $? = 0
configure:5424: result: 
configure:5446: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:5454: /usr/bin/gcc -o conftest    -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   conftest.c  >&5
configure:5458: $? = 0
configure:5465: ./conftest
configure:5469: $? = 0
configure:5484: result: no
configure:5489: checking for suffix of object files
configure:5511: /usr/bin/gcc -c    -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 conftest.c >&5
configure:5515: $? = 0
configure:5536: result: o
configure:5540: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:5559: /usr/bin/gcc -c    -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 conftest.c >&5
configure:5559: $? = 0
configure:5568: result: yes
configure:5577: checking whether /usr/bin/gcc accepts -g
configure:5597: /usr/bin/gcc -c -g  -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 conftest.c >&5
configure:5597: $? = 0
configure:5638: result: yes
configure:5655: checking for /usr/bin/gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:5718: /usr/bin/gcc  -c    -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 conftest.c >&5
configure:5718: $? = 0
configure:5731: result: none needed
configure:5756: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:5826: result: cc -m32 -E
configure:5846: cc -m32 -E  -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 conftest.c
./configure[2168]: eval[1]: cc: not found [No such file or directory]
configure:5846: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:5846: cc -m32 -E  -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 conftest.c
./configure[2168]: eval[1]: cc: not found [No such file or directory]
configure:5846: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:5876: error: in `/export/home/admin/Downloads/Normal_apache/httpd-2.4.25':
configure:5878: error: C preprocessor "cc -m32 -E" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i386-pc-solaris2.11
ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/usr/bin/gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=''
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=''
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=''
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=''
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=''
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=''
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=''
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=''
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=''
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=''
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=''
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=''
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=''
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=''
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=''
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=''
ac_cv_host=i386-pc-solaris2.11
ac_cv_mkdir_p=yes
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_EGREP='/usr/bin/ggrep -E'
ac_cv_path_GREP=/usr/bin/ggrep
ac_cv_prog_CPP='cc -m32 -E'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=/usr/bin/gcc
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=''
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_target=i386-pc-solaris2.11

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

APACHECTL_ULIMIT=''
APR_BINDIR='/usr/apr/1.5/bin'
APR_CONFIG='/usr/apr/1.5/bin/apr-1-config'
APR_INCLUDEDIR='/usr/apr/1.5/include'
APR_VERSION='1.5.1'
APU_BINDIR='/usr/apr-util/1.5/bin'
APU_CONFIG='/usr/apr-util/1.5/bin/apu-1-config'
APU_INCLUDEDIR='/usr/apr-util/1.5/include'
APU_VERSION='1.5.4'
AP_BUILD_SRCLIB_DIRS=''
AP_CLEAN_SRCLIB_DIRS=''
AP_LIBS=''
AWK=''
BUILTIN_LIBS=''
CC='/usr/bin/gcc'
CFLAGS=' '
CORE_IMPLIB=''
CORE_IMPLIB_FILE=''
CPP='cc -m32 -E'
CPPFLAGS=' -DSOLARIS2=11 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
CRYPT_LIBS=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DSO_MODULES=''
DTRACE=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/usr/bin/ggrep -E'
ENABLED_DSO_MODULES=''
EXEEXT=''
EXTRA_CFLAGS=''
EXTRA_CPPFLAGS=''
EXTRA_CXXFLAGS=''
EXTRA_INCLUDES=''
EXTRA_LDFLAGS=''
EXTRA_LIBS=''
GREP='/usr/bin/ggrep'
HTTPD_LDFLAGS=''
HTTPD_MMN='20120211'
HTTPD_VERSION='2.4.25'
INCLUDES=''
INSTALL=''
INSTALL_DSO=''
INSTALL_PROG_FLAGS=''
INTERNAL_CPPFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS=' '
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LN_S=''
LOAD_ALL_MODULES=''
LTCFLAGS=''
LTFLAGS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_LDFLAGS=''
LUA_CFLAGS=''
LUA_LIBS=''
LYNX_PATH=''
MATH_LIBS=''
MKDEP=''
MKINSTALLDIRS=''
MK_IMPLIB=''
MODULE_CLEANDIRS=''
MODULE_DIRS=''
MOD_ACCESS_COMPAT_LDADD=''
MOD_ACTIONS_LDADD=''
MOD_ALIAS_LDADD=''
MOD_ALLOWMETHODS_LDADD=''
MOD_ASIS_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHNZ_FCGI_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHNZ_LDAP_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHN_ANON_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHN_CORE_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHN_DBD_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHN_DBM_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHN_FILE_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHN_SOCACHE_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHZ_CORE_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHZ_DBD_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHZ_DBM_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHZ_GROUPFILE_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHZ_HOST_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHZ_OWNER_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTHZ_USER_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTH_BASIC_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTH_DIGEST_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTH_FORM_LDADD=''
MOD_AUTOINDEX_LDADD=''
MOD_BUCKETEER_LDADD=''
MOD_BUFFER_LDADD=''
MOD_CACHE_DISK_LDADD=''
MOD_CACHE_LDADD=''
MOD_CACHE_SOCACHE_LDADD=''
MOD_CASE_FILTER_IN_LDADD=''
MOD_CASE_FILTER_LDADD=''
MOD_CERN_META_LDADD=''
MOD_CGID_LDADD=''
MOD_CGI_LDADD=''
MOD_CHARSET_LITE_LDADD=''
MOD_DATA_LDADD=''
MOD_DAV_FS_LDADD=''
MOD_DAV_LDADD=''
MOD_DAV_LOCK_LDADD=''
MOD_DBD_LDADD=''
MOD_DEFLATE_LDADD=''
MOD_DIALUP_LDADD=''
MOD_DIR_LDADD=''
MOD_DUMPIO_LDADD=''
MOD_ECHO_LDADD=''
MOD_ENV_LDADD=''
MOD_EXAMPLE_HOOKS_LDADD=''
MOD_EXAMPLE_IPC_LDADD=''
MOD_EXPIRES_LDADD=''
MOD_EXT_FILTER_LDADD=''
MOD_FILE_CACHE_LDADD=''
MOD_FILTER_LDADD=''
MOD_HEADERS_LDADD=''
MOD_HEARTBEAT_LDADD=''
MOD_HEARTMONITOR_LDADD=''
MOD_HTTP2_LDADD=''
MOD_HTTP_LDADD=''
MOD_IDENT_LDADD=''
MOD_IMAGEMAP_LDADD=''
MOD_INCLUDE_LDADD=''
MOD_INFO_LDADD=''
MOD_ISAPI_LDADD=''
MOD_LBMETHOD_BYBUSYNESS_LDADD=''
MOD_LBMETHOD_BYREQUESTS_LDADD=''
MOD_LBMETHOD_BYTRAFFIC_LDADD=''
MOD_LBMETHOD_HEARTBEAT_LDADD=''
MOD_LDAP_LDADD=''
MOD_LOGIO_LDADD=''
MOD_LOG_CONFIG_LDADD=''
MOD_LOG_DEBUG_LDADD=''
MOD_LOG_FORENSIC_LDADD=''
MOD_LUA_LDADD=''
MOD_MACRO_LDADD=''
MOD_MIME_LDADD=''
MOD_MIME_MAGIC_LDADD=''
MOD_MPM_EVENT_LDADD=''
MOD_NEGOTIATION_LDADD=''
MOD_OPTIONAL_FN_EXPORT_LDADD=''
MOD_OPTIONAL_FN_IMPORT_LDADD=''
MOD_OPTIONAL_HOOK_EXPORT_LDADD=''
MOD_OPTIONAL_HOOK_IMPORT_LDADD=''
MOD_PRIVILEGES_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_AJP_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_BALANCER_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_CONNECT_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_EXPRESS_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_FCGI_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_FDPASS_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_FTP_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_HCHECK_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_HTML_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_HTTP2_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_HTTP_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_SCGI_LDADD=''
MOD_PROXY_WSTUNNEL_LDADD=''
MOD_RATELIMIT_LDADD=''
MOD_REFLECTOR_LDADD=''
MOD_REMOTEIP_LDADD=''
MOD_REQTIMEOUT_LDADD=''
MOD_REQUEST_LDADD=''
MOD_REWRITE_LDADD=''
MOD_SED_LDADD=''
MOD_SESSION_COOKIE_LDADD=''
MOD_SESSION_CRYPTO_LDADD=''
MOD_SESSION_DBD_LDADD=''
MOD_SESSION_LDADD=''
MOD_SETENVIF_LDADD=''
MOD_SLOTMEM_PLAIN_LDADD=''
MOD_SLOTMEM_SHM_LDADD=''
MOD_SOCACHE_DBM_LDADD=''
MOD_SOCACHE_DC_LDADD=''
MOD_SOCACHE_MEMCACHE_LDADD=''
MOD_SOCACHE_SHMCB_LDADD=''
MOD_SO_ENABLED=''
MOD_SO_LDADD=''
MOD_SPELING_LDADD=''
MOD_SSL_LDADD=''
MOD_STATUS_LDADD=''
MOD_SUBSTITUTE_LDADD=''
MOD_SUEXEC_LDADD=''
MOD_UNIQUE_ID_LDADD=''
MOD_UNIXD_LDADD=''
MOD_USERDIR_LDADD=''
MOD_USERTRACK_LDADD=''
MOD_VERSION_LDADD=''
MOD_VHOST_ALIAS_LDADD=''
MOD_WATCHDOG_LDADD=''
MOD_XML2ENC_LDADD=''
MPM_LIB=''
MPM_SUBDIRS=''
NONPORTABLE_SUPPORT=''
NOTEST_CFLAGS=''
NOTEST_CPPFLAGS=''
NOTEST_CXXFLAGS=''
NOTEST_LDFLAGS=''
NOTEST_LIBS=''
OBJEXT='o'
OS=''
OS_DIR=''
OS_SPECIFIC_VARS=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PCRE_CONFIG=''
PCRE_LIBS=''
PICFLAGS=''
PILDFLAGS=''
PKGCONFIG=''
PORT=''
POST_SHARED_CMDS=''
PRE_SHARED_CMDS=''
RANLIB=''
RM=''
RSYNC=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SHLIBPATH_VAR='LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
SHLTCFLAGS=''
SH_LDFLAGS=''
SH_LIBS=''
SH_LIBTOOL=''
SSLPORT=''
UTIL_LDFLAGS=''
ab_CFLAGS=''
ab_LDFLAGS=''
ab_LTFLAGS=''
abs_srcdir='/export/home/admin/Downloads/Normal_apache/httpd-2.4.25'
ac_ct_CC='/usr/bin/gcc'
ap_make_delimiter=''
ap_make_include=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i386-pc-solaris2.11'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i386'
build_os='solaris2.11'
build_vendor='pc'
cgidir='${datadir}/cgi-bin'
checkgid_LTFLAGS=''
datadir='${prefix}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
errordir='${datadir}/error'
exec_prefix='${prefix}'
exp_bindir='/opt/app/apache/bin'
exp_cgidir='/opt/app/apache/cgi-bin'
exp_datadir='/opt/app/apache'
exp_errordir='/opt/app/apache/error'
exp_exec_prefix='/opt/app/apache'
exp_htdocsdir='/opt/app/apache/htdocs'
exp_iconsdir='/opt/app/apache/icons'
exp_includedir='/opt/app/apache/include'
exp_installbuilddir='/opt/app/apache/build'
exp_libdir='/opt/app/apache/lib'
exp_libexecdir='/opt/app/apache/modules'
exp_localstatedir='/opt/app/apache'
exp_logfiledir='/opt/app/apache/logs'
exp_mandir='/opt/app/apache/man'
exp_manualdir='/opt/app/apache/manual'
exp_proxycachedir='/opt/app/apache/proxy'
exp_runtimedir='/opt/app/apache/logs'
exp_sbindir='/opt/app/apache/bin'
exp_sysconfdir='/opt/app/apache/conf'
fcgistarter_LTFLAGS=''
host='i386-pc-solaris2.11'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i386'
host_os='solaris2.11'
host_vendor='pc'
htcacheclean_LTFLAGS=''
htdbm_LTFLAGS=''
htdigest_LTFLAGS=''
htdocsdir='${datadir}/htdocs'
htmldir='${docdir}'
htpasswd_LTFLAGS=''
httxt2dbm_LTFLAGS=''
iconsdir='${datadir}/icons'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
installbuilddir='${datadir}/build'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/modules'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}'
logfiledir='${localstatedir}/logs'
logresolve_LTFLAGS=''
mandir='${prefix}/man'
manualdir='${datadir}/manual'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
other_targets=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
perlbin=''
prefix='/opt/app/apache'
progname=''
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
proxycachedir='${localstatedir}/proxy'
psdir='${docdir}'
rel_bindir='bin'
rel_cgidir='cgi-bin'
rel_datadir=''
rel_errordir='error'
rel_exec_prefix=''
rel_htdocsdir='htdocs'
rel_iconsdir='icons'
rel_includedir='include'
rel_installbuilddir='build'
rel_libdir='lib'
rel_libexecdir='modules'
rel_localstatedir=''
rel_logfiledir='logs'
rel_mandir='man'
rel_manualdir='manual'
rel_proxycachedir='proxy'
rel_runtimedir='logs'
rel_sbindir='bin'
rel_sysconfdir='conf'
rotatelogs_LTFLAGS=''
runtimedir='${localstatedir}/logs'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
shared_build=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/conf'
target='i386-pc-solaris2.11'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='i386'
target_os='solaris2.11'
target_vendor='pc'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 1
```

I also have tried CPP='cc -m64 -E'. Failed.

Can anyone point me put what did I missing? Multilib for solaris gcc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C pre-processor is being invoked incorrectly; you need to help `./configure` out by setting the `CPP` variable:

```
CC='/usr/bin/gcc' CPP='/usr/bin/gcc -E' ./configure --prefix=/opt/app/apache --with-pcre=~/Downloads/pcre-8.40
```

Comment: Thank you. It work. Although next step which are "make" failed,  I found work around.